# Name of implement used for cleaning under your nails?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the correct term for the implement (usually with a little flat hook) used to clean under finger- and toenails?

**EDIT:** found an image.  This is the doodad I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ***[Nail file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nail_file), [nail pusher](https://www.google.it/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=nail%20file%20meaning&oq=nail%20file%20meaning&gs_l=tablet-gws.3..0i19j0i22i30i19l2.2937.8354.0.8601.23.20.3.0.0.0.229.1865.14j5j1.20.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..0.23.1876._hxHrMTw7PY#q=nail%20file%20for%20cleaning%20under%20the%20nail)  or cleaner*** is  what you would use:

> - A nail file is a tool used to gently grind down and shape the edges of nails. They are often used in manicures and pedicures after the nail has been trimmed using appropriate nail clippers.

[image] *Nail pusher/cleaner*

Comment: Keys, tweezers, and credit cards are used pretty often too.

Comment: See updated question with image.  What is that specific implement called?

Comment: @Ricky - LOL :D

Comment: @ShaulBehr - that a nail file with a hook for cleaning. A nail cleaner.